Is thread_local in C only useful for objects that don't require clean-up?
In C, suppose I have something like:
struct node {
  struct node *next;
  void *data;
};

static thread_local struct node *head;

that is, a linked list per thread.  If I want to ensure that all elements on the list are automamtically freed upon thread termination, how can this be done?
C does have tss_create() that allows you to create thread-specific storage and provide a destructor function to clean it up upon thread termination, but that seems orthogonal to objects declared thread_local.
There doesn't seem to be an analogous way to specify a destructor for thread_local objects — hence thread_local seems useful only for objects that do not require clean-up automatically, like int or similar.
True?

Note that I'm asking only about C — not C++.
With the exception of the above, please assume I know how C works. I’ve been coding in C since the late 1980s.
If a thread just calls thrd_exit and if head points to a list of nodes, will all those nodes leak?
Yes, I know that the thread itself can call any function it wants including a clean-up function.  I'm asking specifically and only if there's a way to set things up in advance such that clean-up is done automatically for thread_local objects just like for tss_created objects.
FYI: If it's not possible, then that's the answer.

For almost everything, C doesn't really have automatic destruction of objects. The normal way is to have a create or allocate functions, matched by destroy or free functions.

I believe what you're looking for is the default behavior. Each thread manage its own memory, unless you specify static like you did within a function, and each thread uses this same function

@Someprogrammerdude I know how C works. Your comment doesn’t specifically answer my question.

I don't think this is about the head pointer, @Mike. It's rather about where it points and what other memory is linked to it, which may require more than the trivial cleanup.

@UlrichEckhardt Yes, hence “… all elements on the list …” in my question.

"hence thread_local seems useful only for objects that do not require clean-up" - I don't see a difference between cleaning up a thread_local from cleaning up any other resource. Just do the cleanup of the thread_local before exiting the thread.

@TedLyngmo And if a thread calls thrd_exit?

@TedLyngmo I've revised my question to be even more explicit. I mean automatic clean-up — just like you get via tss_create — but for thread_local objects.

@PaulJ.Lucas If you have allocated resources that needs to be released, then call the function that releases the resources, just like you would if head had not been thread_local.  If you want the call automatically, you can still use tss_create to get a callback when the thread exits: tss_set(key, &head);

@TedLyngmo OK... that's what I was thinking, but it seems kind of silly, so I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.


tss_create() ... seems orthogonal to objects declared thread_local.

Yep. No objects in C are automatically cleaned up except where you explicitly register a function to do it. thread_local is a storage-class specifier just like static. A static pointer doesn't have any automatic cleanup mechanism either.
If you want automatic cleanup, there's C++ RAII.
Assuming you stick with C, your options are:

Use tss_create instead.

Use a dummy tss_create as well, just to register the destructor.
Sounds silly, but there I guess there might be cases where it makes sense.

Write your own thread_local clean-up mechanism in your top-level thread function

Use C++ (sorry)



Thread-local objects are an essential part of most recipes for ensuring reliable object cleanup.  If C were to specify a particular mechanism for object cleanup during "stack unwinding" as part of the language, such a mechanism would likely be incompatible with other mechanisms that many platforms may already provide for such a purpose.  If all code uses the same thread-local jmp_buff object for stack unwinding, and follows the pattern:
jmp_buf *saved_exit,my_exit;
saved_exit = global_exit;    
if (setjmp(my_exit))
{
  ... do necessary cleanup, then ...
  global_exit = saved_exit;
  longjmp(global_exit, 1)
}
... remainder of function goes here

then any object cleanup that would be necessary during an "emergency exit" can be accomplished as needed.  Bad things may happen if a function which uses one emergency-exit springboard calls a function which sets up another, which then calls code that exits via the first (bypassing the second), but if all code uses the same jmp_buf pointer there's no need for any code to care about what kinds of cleanup might be required by code higher or lower on the call stack.

This has nothing to do with stack unwinding. I'm not asking about clean-up of objects on the stack. I'm asking only about objects declared thread_local.

@PaulJ.Lucas: The notion of "stack unwinding" is for cleaning up resources which exist somewhere other than the stack.  Essentially, the sequence of calling contexts (stored on the stack) implies what would happen if functions return normally.  If a function acquires a resource, calls another function, and would then clean up a resource if that called function returns normally, the calling context would inherently contain an obligation to ensure that the resource gets cleaned up.  With the aid of the pattern above, a called function could either return normally or longjmp(*global_exit,1);.

My main point was that C does not provide resource cleanup as a language feature, but provides the tools necessary for programmers to accomplish whatever needs to be done.

No, "stack unwinding" really is only about cleaning up resources on the stack — that's why it's literally called "stack unwinding." Re: second commend: maybe not as a language feature, but tss_create as a standard library feature certainly does provide resource clean-up.

If you control all the code and threads in the application, you can use thread_local with such structure. You just need to call your own clean up function before thrd_exit.
Not useful for libraries, or more generic code, but technically thread_local can be used with objects that need clean up.
